# warning: implicit declaration of function 'foo' is invalid in C99

Tags: c

I got another question in C programming. I followed an example in the Book "Programming in C" and wrote the following two source files:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i = 5;

int main(void)
{
  printf("%i ", i);

  foo();

  printf("%i\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

and
**foo.c:**

```
extern int i;

void foo(void)
{
  i = 100;
}
```

Problem arises when I compile 'gcc main.c foo.c':

> main.c:9:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'foo' is invalid
>   in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]   foo();   ^ 1 warning
>   generated.

I found a work around by renaming foo.c to foo.h and include it as header in main.c. Is this a good way of making it work? How to make it work with foo.c ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a header with declaration of the function foo. Leave foo.c as is and create foo.h with the declaration

```
void foo(void);
```

Then include foo.h in main.c and in foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

Comment: And include it in `foo.c` as well.  And don't forget to wrap the contents of `foo.h` with an `#ifndef` guard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the signature of `foo` in a header and include it in main.c

foo.h:

```
void foo(void);
```

in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"
// Rest of code
```